# Get campaign error while sending to recipients

Tags: surveymonkey

I am working on the surveymonkey API and I am trying to send a message throw an email collector. The first send is ok but I get the error : 409 :
Campaign status is completed when I send to a new contact.

Do I have to create a new collector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to create a new collector but you have to create a new message (unless you close your collector, which you can re-open).

See the [documentation for collectors/messages](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#collectors-and-invite-messages) on how to create collectors and messages.

Example:

Create a [new collector](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#surveys-id-collectors):

```
POST /surveys/<survey_id>/collectors
{
    "type": "email"
}
```

That'll return the collector you just created, you can then [add a message](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#collectors-id-messages) to that collector:

```
POST /v3/collectors/<collector_id>/messages
{
    "type": "invite"
}
```

You can then [add recipients](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#collectors-id-messages-id-recipients) to your message:

```
POST /v3/collectors/<collector_id>/messages/<message_id>/recipients
{
    "email": "test@example.com"
}
```

Then [send that message](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#collectors-id-messages-id-send).

```
POST /v3/collectors/<collector_id>/messages/<message_id>/send
```

You can then do steps 2-4 above on the same collector to create new messages, add recipients, then send it out. You can keep using the same collector.